# How to change GDI's scanline size from 216 bytes to 210 bytes

Tags: mfc, gdi

I want to send change the GDI's scanline size from 216 bytes tp 210 bytes.

My application sends the data to GDI. And through port monitor, data is passed to my driver for printing. My driver accepts the data as 210 bytes per scanline, but GDI sends 216 bytes per scanline. Is it possible to change the GDI's  scanline size from 216 bytes to 210 bytes.

Application code:-

```
CDC printDC;    
printDC.StartPage();
printDC.Rectangle(0,0,wsize.cx - 105,-wsize.cy + 20);
printDC.TextOut(5,-5,tout);
printDC.TextOut(5,-wsize.cy + 70,PageNum);
printDC.EndPage();
```

Bytes sent to the driver in a gdi packet as :-

```
#define GDI_BYTES               1728 //(216 * 8)
```

Expected :-

Driver should get 210 bytes per scanline.

Actual:-

Driver is getting 216 bytes per scanline.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What *problem* are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I am new to this Printer domain.I don't have much idea about it.  My problem is that my driver accepts 210 bytes per scanline, but GDI sends 216 bytes per scanline. I want to know - Is there a way that GDI sends 210 bytes per scanline, instead of 216 bytes.

Comment: Please read the documentation on [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) (or the respective [MFC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/device-contexts)).